# How to connect to a database on the server side in a GWT project?

Tags: gwt, database-connection

I am designing a simple authentication application using GWT. There is no processing done on the client side. On the server side there is a authenticate() function which should connect to a database and return a string "success" or "failure "to the client. I am executing the code in the development mode. I am using a sybase database. I have added the required jar files in war/WEB-INF/lib as well as in the build path. But i am facing issues in  connecting to a database. Database driver gets loaded successfully but getConnection() method shows a lot of RPC exceptions when i try running the webapp. Can anyone please help.. ??

Comment: It shows this mesage in console tab in ecilipse..Dec 13, 2011 1:51:06 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.ericsson.authentication.client.AuthenticationService.authenticate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.Socket is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

Comment: Google App Engine? Try disabling GAE in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect from client side, you can only do that in server part of the code. Read thoroughly this: [GWT documentation on client-server communication](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html).

The actual work of the authenticate() method should be placed inside com.ericsson.authentication.server.AuthenticationServiceImpl class, and authenticate inside com.ericsson.authentication.client.AuthenticationService class should only refer to server counterpart.

Comment: U got it wrong..m not trying to connect to a database from client side..the server side code is trying to connect to database but still is not able to..The getConnection() method is not working properly..some sort of unknown exception is thrown at getConnection()..why it could be so..?